# Deleting Rows that contain criteria in specific columnn

Tags: excel, vba

Quick question.

I have this macro below which looks if column B contains a 0 value.  In the instance that it does, it deletes that row.  This works well until there are instances where no rows contain a zero, and then it throws an error saying it's out of range.

is it possible to tweak this so that it runs without an error, and just doesn't delete anything if it can't find a row with a 0 in Column B?

```
Sub Deletezero()

Dim LastRow As Long, ReadRow As Long, n As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

ReadRow = 1
For n = 1 To LastRow
  If Range("B" & ReadRow).Value Like "*0*" = True Then
      Range("H" & ReadRow).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
      ReadRow = ReadRow + 1
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You're deleting rows the wrong way. Use `For n = LastRow to 1 Step -1` and `n`, instead of `ReadRow`. Even better, use `Union` to construct a range to delete and delete it after looping.

Comment: Are you able to use `AutoFilter` to filter for just the rows to delete, delete them, and then remove the filter?  (n.b. this won't be an option if there is already a filter on the sheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It should be faster then yours, deleting all rows (if any to be deleted) at once, at the end. In fact, the code only select the rows. If the selection is correct, please replace `Select` with `Delete`:

```
Sub Deletezero()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, n As Long, rngDel As Range

 Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 LastRow = sh.cells(sh.rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row

 For n = 1 To LastRow
   If sh.Range("B" & n).Value Like "*0*" Then
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then
            Set rngDel = sh.Range("B" & n)
        Else
            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Range("B" & n))
        End If
     End If
 Next
 If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Select 'if it selects what you need, please replace Select with Delete
End Sub
```